# Better way to mock class attribute in python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I have a base class that defines a class attribute and some child classes that depend on it, e.g.

```
class Base(object):
    assignment = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

I want to unittest this class with different *assignments*, e.g. empty dictionary, single item, etc. This is extremely simplified of course, it's not a matter of refactoring my classes or tests

The (pytest) tests I have come up with, eventually, that work are

```
from .base import Base

def test_empty(self):
    with mock.patch("base.Base.assignment") as a:
        a.__get__ = mock.Mock(return_value={})
        assert len(Base().assignment.values()) == 0

def test_single(self):
    with mock.patch("base.Base.assignment") as a:
        a.__get__ = mock.Mock(return_value={'a':1})
        assert len(Base().assignment.values()) == 1
```

This feels rather complicated and hacky - I don't even fully understand why it works (I am familiar with descriptors though). Does mock automagically transform class attributes into descriptors?

A solution that would feel more logical does not work:

```
def test_single(self):
    with mock.patch("base.Base") as a:
        a.assignment = mock.PropertyMock(return_value={'a':1})
        assert len(Base().assignment.values()) == 1
```

or just

```
def test_single(self):
    with mock.patch("base.Base") as a:
        a.assignment = {'a':1}
        assert len(Base().assignment.values()) == 1
```

Other variants that I've tried don't work either (assignments remains unchanged in the test).

What's the proper way to mock a class attribute? Is there a better / more understandable way than the one above?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`base.Base.assignment` is simply replaced with a `Mock` object. You *made* it a descriptor by adding a `__get__` method.

It's a little verbose and a little unnecessary; you could simply set `base.Base.assignment` directly:

```
def test_empty(self):
    Base.assignment = {}
    assert len(Base().assignment.values()) == 0
```

This isn't too safe when using test concurrency, of course.

To use a `PropertyMock`, I'd use:

```
with patch('base.Base.assignment', new_callable=PropertyMock) as a:
    a.return_value = {'a': 1}
```

or even:

```
with patch('base.Base.assignment', new_callable=PropertyMock, 
           return_value={'a': 1}):
```

Comment: Bar.assignment.__get__ = lambda: {1:1} wouldn't have worked here (just tried), so mock injects/mocks a descriptor. Also, mock takes care of restoring the 'old' definition which avoids nasty side effects when modifying globally this way. I can do some old school hacking around like you suggest (and I use to) but I want to learn the 'mock' way :)

Comment: @IvovanderWijk: With `Bar.assignment` being a mock?

Comment: @IvovanderWijk: I am surprised that `PropertyMock` didn't work though.

Comment: Either by partially mocking Bar or by only mocking the 'assignment' attribute, whatever the mock module provides.

Comment: new_callable is a good suggestion. PropertyMock(return_value={'a':1}) makes it even better :) (no need for the 'as a' or further assignment anymore)

Comment: @IvovanderWijk: as for `Bar.assignment.__get__ = lambda: {'a': 1}`; that won't work because the `__get__` *method* would need to accept `self`, `obj` and `type_` arguments.. The `Mock` object at least uses `*args, **kwargs` signatures for their callables.

Comment: No, python refuses the assignment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__get__'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49479/discussion-between-ivo-van-der-wijk-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: @IvovanderWijk: That'd be correct, because `dict()` objects do not support setting additional attributes (there is no `.__dict__` attribute on dictionaries).

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer helped me somuch!

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't this possible without using `PropertyMock`?

```
with mock.patch.object(Base, 'assignment', {'bucket': 'head'}):
   # do stuff
```

Comment: The third positional argument here is the `new=` keyword argument. It actually looks pretty good as a positional argument, but function calls with more than two positional arguments always make me feel a bit nervous....

Comment: The fact that this works does make me think that `PropertyMock` might not need to exist??

Answer (score 12):

To improve readability you can use the `@patch` decorator:

```
from mock import patch
from unittest import TestCase

from base import Base

class MyTest(TestCase):
    @patch('base.Base.assignment')
    def test_empty(self, mock_assignment):
        # The `mock_assignment` is a MagicMock instance,
        # you can do whatever you want to it.
        mock_assignment.__get__.return_value = {}

        self.assertEqual(len(Base().assignment.values()), 0)
        # ... and so on
```

You can find more details at http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#mock.patch.

Comment: Good point. Didn't get the decorated to work with pytest at first (it conflicted with pytest's fixture argument 'injection') but it turns out to be a matter of proper argument order (patches go first)

Comment: It seems that since mock-1.0.1 it isn't an issue anymore:

https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/pytest/issue/217/mockpatch-decorator-and-test-fixtures-don

Answer (score 7):

If your class (Queue for example) in *already imported* inside your test - and you want to patch **MAX_RETRY** attr - you can use **[@patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object)** or simply better **[@patch.multiple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-multiple)**

```
from mock import patch, PropertyMock, Mock
from somewhere import Queue

@patch.multiple(Queue, MAX_RETRY=1, some_class_method=Mock)
def test_something(self):
    do_something()


@patch.object(Queue, 'MAX_RETRY', return_value=1, new_callable=PropertyMock)
def test_something(self, _mocked):
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example how to unit-test your `Base` class:

- mocking *multiple class attributes* of different types (ie: `dict` and `int`)
- using the `@patch` decorator and `pytest` framework with  with `python 2.7+` or `3+`.

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
try: #python 3
    from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock
except ImportError as e: #python 2
    from mock import patch, PropertyMock 

from base import Base

@patch('base.Base.assign_dict', new_callable=PropertyMock, return_value=dict(a=1, b=2, c=3))
@patch('base.Base.assign_int',  new_callable=PropertyMock, return_value=9765)
def test_type(mock_dict, mock_int):
    """Test if mocked class attributes have correct types"""
    assert isinstance(Base().assign_dict, dict)
    assert isinstance(Base().assign_int , int)
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers seem to have missed something.

In my case I had a simple file with some constants at the top, like this:

```
LIB_DIR_PATH_STR = 'some_path_to_module'
```

After this I have a method during which I add this library to `sys.path` prior to importing it:

```
def main():
    ...
    sys.path.append(LIB_DIR_PATH_STR)
```

... but what I wanted to do in testing is to mock LIB_DIR_PATH_STR, so that it points to a non-existent path, i.e. for error-handling. Here we're not talking about mocking any classes or even methods in a script.

However, it turns out that it is possible (where `my_script` has previously been imported):

```
with mock.patch.object(my_script, 'LIB_DIR_PATH_STR', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock(return_value=non_existent_dir_path_str)):
    my_script.main()
```

... i.e. `PropertyMock` can be instantiated with a `return_value` of its own. The is not the same as specifying the `return_value` for a patch in which a `PropertyMock` is *participating* (the class of the patch will then be `Mock` or maybe `MagicMock`). The latter approach simply won't work for this simple "replace a string with another" type of mock: pytest will complain "expected string but got Mock".

My specific example is tangential to the question (class attributes), to show how it's done. But it can be used with class attributes too...