# Mocking form in class based view not using the MagicMock

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, python-mock, django-unittest

I've been fighting with mocking a form class to replace an instance of it in a class-based view. But it looks like that because the form is in a class attribute, it happens *before* I replace the form class with my mock. Case in point:

**app/views.py**

```py
from app.forms import SomeForm  # For some reason, this _is_ my mock...

class SomeViewClass(View):
    form = SomeForm  # ... while this is the _real_ SomeForm

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form(request.POST, request.FILES)

        # Hacked around with pdb here
        # (Pdb) self.form = SomeForm <-- Force the mock into the object
        # (Pdb) form = self.form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # (Pdb) form.is_valid() is now True
        # (Pdb) continue <--- Test finishes, and asserts are OK.

        if form.is_valid():  # This fails, as I'm running the real code
            # code, code, code
```

**app/tests/test_views.py**

```py
from mock import MagicMock, patch

from django.tests import Client, TestCase


@patch('app.views.SomeForm')
    def test_post_valid_form_should_pass(self, mocked_form_class):
        """ Replacing SomeForm in SomeViewClass to pas the is_valid test
        """
        form_instance = MagicMock(spec=SomeForm())
        form_instance.is_valid.return_value = True
        mocked_form_class.return_value = form_instance

        self.client.login(**self.credentials)
        # code, code, code
```

As you can see in the inserted comments in `app/views.py`, I forcefully reloaded `self.form` and redefined the variable `form` using pdb, which made my test pass.

It seems that for some reason, the `SomeViewClass` is [registered,instanciated,...] before I start patching `SomeForm`. Any ideas on that?

Comment: How about if you do `@patch('app.views.SomeForm.form')`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `form` is an attribute of `SomeViewClass` not of `SomeForm`

Comment: @DanielRoseman That was it! Thanks a lot. Although foxyblue is right on the location of the attribute. Could you make it an answer for me to validate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the view is already loaded by Django and the `form` field is already defined and pointing to the `SomeForm` *production* class.

As @DanielRoseman and @foxyblue pointed out in their comments, it is possible to patch directly a field in a class. And actually [there was already an answer for that on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42180559/2441358). As pointed out, it is possible to use `patch.object` [to patch a member of a class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object) (which is, IMO, the best solution, as it's more explicit, and less prone to typos)

### Test corrected:

**With `patch`**

```py
@patch('app.views.SomeView.form', autospec=SomeForm)
    def test_post_valid_form_should_pass(self, mocked_form_class):
        """ Replacing SomeForm in SomeViewClass.form to pass the is_valid test """
        mocked_form_class.is_valid.return_value = True

        self.client.login(**self.credentials)
        # code, code, code
```

**With `patch.object`**

```py
@patch.object(SomeView, 'form', autospec=SomeForm)
    def test_post_valid_form_should_pass(self, mocked_form_class):
        """ Replacing SomeForm in SomeViewClass.form to pass the is_valid test """
        mocked_form_class.is_valid.return_value = True

        self.client.login(**self.credentials)
        # code, code, code
```