# Mocking a class attribute

Tags: python, class, mocking, pytest

I have a class with a single class attribute that I want to mock

my_class.py

```
class MyClass:

    __attribute = ['123', '456']
```

test_my_class.py

```
import pytest
from directory.my_class import MyClass

def test_1(mocker):
    with mocker.patch.object(MyClass, '__attribute', {'something': 'new'}):
        test = MyClass()
```

I get:

```
E           AttributeError: <class 'directory.my_class.MyClass'> does not have the attribute '__attribute'
```

I also get the same error when trying:

```
def test_2(mocker):
    with mocker.patch('directory.my_class.MyClass.__attribute', new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock) as a:
        a.return_value = {'something': 'new'}
        test = MyClass()
```

I've also tried a direct assignment along with the other suggestions in this post:
[Better way to mock class attribute in python unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324628/better-way-to-mock-class-attribute-in-python-unit-test)

My project is using a mocker fixture from this plugin: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/

Comment: `__attribute` is subject to name mangling; I would avoid using `__`-prefixed names until you see a reason to use one. If you want to suggest that it is private to the class, `_attribute` will be sufficient.

Comment: IMO I would avoid using double underscore class attributes. The name mangling has more headaches than it's worth. Also if a variable is private, then tests should ideally not be accessing it. Make it a defaultable ctor parameter so you can place appropriate values in tests without patching.

Comment: thanks both - will avoid the double underscore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do above with a `PropertyMock`

```
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock

class MyClass:
  attr = [1, 2, 3]

with patch.object(MyClass, "attr", new_callable=PropertyMock) as attr_mock:
  attr_mock.return_value = [4, 5, 6]

  print(MyClass.attr) # prints [4, 5, 6]

print(MyClass.attr) # prints [1, 2, 3]
```

For a docs reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock

Comment: I get:

"E       AttributeError: \_\_enter\__"

Comment: You can try this live (and in isolation): https://replit.com/@eelkevdbos/HighlevelMistySection#main.py

Comment: Yeah just tried it and it worked.. must be something in my env - thanks

Comment: The `__enter__` error hints that the class (or instance of it) is used as a context manager somewhere.