# How to mock a function called in a class attribute in python

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I need to mock a function that is called in a class attribute in a python class. I'm able to do it patching the function when the object is initialised, but it does not work when I access it without creating an instance. See the code below:

```
# methods.py

def bar():
    return "bar"
```

```
# foo.py
from methods import bar

class Foo:
    class_attribute = bar()
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.class_attribute = bar()
```

```
#test_foo.py
from foo import Foo
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("foo.bar")
    def test_mock_foo(self, mock):
        mock.return_value = "patched foo"
        print(Foo.class_attribute) # it prints "bar"
        print(Foo().class_attribute) # it prints "patched foo"

unittest.main(argv=[''], verbosity=0,exit=False)
```

How is it possible to mock the function without mocking the class attribute?

Comment: The function is called at class _definition_ time, i.e. when you import it and therefore before you mock it. Either the coupling is correct and it shouldn't be mocked, or you should decouple them.

Comment: There is a difference between the 2 'class_attributes' in the Foo class. The first one is a static variable (shared between all instances of Foo) and the second (defined in the constructor) is a local variable. I would advise you to name them differently (or remove the static one if it wasn't your intent to have one) to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @Billuc I did the example that way on purpose to explain the problem. So do you know if it's possible to mock the class attribute in any way?

Comment: @jonrsharpe what do you mean by decoupling?

Comment: I think the naming adds more confusion to understand your problem than anything... Anyways, you won't be able to mock the class attribute without modifying foo.py. As @jonrsharpe said `bar` is called at class definition time (in other words, when you import Foo, bar is called to init class_attribute, so calling patch after that wont modify the value). As class_attribute is static, it shouldn't be mocked as it is a common variable for all the instances of the class (imagine modifying the behaviour of all the instances of a class by modifying a variable, that's chaos; and bad practice)

Comment: @Billuc I named the variables with the same name to make the problem clearer, but I see that it confused a little. My question is still open, is it possible to mock the return value of the called function in a class attribute somehow for testing purposes?

Comment: Short answer : no, for the reasons we explained previously. If we weren't clear, let us know and we will try to explain in other words

Comment: So maybe not with patching but is there any other way to mock it out? @Billuc

Comment: Quick google search lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324628/better-way-to-mock-class-attribute-in-python-unit-test), but it is using Pytest and mocking the attribute and not the method. You can also use the property and classmethod decorators to achieve the same result in a more decoupled way (and patchable but requires Python>3.9)